# Unable to refresh data in Excel Online connected using Power Query

Tags: office-365, excel

I have prepared a chart in Excel, connected using Power Query. In Power Query I have used oData connection to get a SharePoint Online List to get the data.

Now I save the Excel into Office 365 Document library.

If I refresh the data in Excel File then I am able to refresh data in Excel file. But I am not able to refresh the data in Excel Online. I am getting the following error,

> We were unable to refresh one or more data connections in this workbook. 
>   The following connections failed to refresh: 
>   Query - ABC

Is it possible to refresh data in Excel Online directly? Or any other way to refresh data in Excel Online?

Answer (score 3):

Clearest answer I've found to this is [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1d4a4875-4492-4efb-b684-d31be99efe0f/data-model-refresh-on-sharepoint-online-with-power-query?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel#4c154fd2-5dfa-4116-b558-47cb080372dc):

> SharePoint doesn't support refreshing Power Query data sources at the
>   present time.  Although it's true that SharePoint and SharePoint
>   Online don't currently support Power Query refreshes, the error
>   message you get is related to not being able to refresh from the Data
>   Model which is something SharePoint Online isn't able to do
>   (on-premise SharePoint can).

Comment: Does anyone know if this is still true in 2020?  Running into the same error.